# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Change Permissions on Mounted Directory

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a Laravel application to a multicontainer Elastic Beanstalk configuration. The application code is packaged in a zip file and uploaded as part of the deployment, and is then mounted into the PHP-FPM Docker container. The containers run correctly and the code is mounted, however all the mounted directories are owned by `root` and therefore the application cannot write to these directories (required for log files, framework files etc). I need them to be owned by `www-data`

If I manually SSH on the the EC2 instance, then run `docker exec -it container_id bash` and run `ls -la` I can see all the files/dirs are owned by root. If I run `chown -R www-data: storage vendor` then the application works as expected.

**Therefore I need to find a way to change the permissions on the mounted directories *inside* the php-fpm container.**

I have tried the following command in `.ebextensions/permissions.config`

```
container_commands:
  01_change_storage_permissions:
    # Get the php fpm container ID and change permissions on the mounted directories
    command: sudo docker exec $(sudo docker ps -aqf "name=php-fpm") chown -R www-data:www-data storage vendor bootstrap
```

The deployment is successful so I can assume the command executed successfully but it unfortunately doesn't seem to change the permissions as upon logging into the container, the directories are still owned by root

Answer (score 2):

You can `chown` the directories before mounting them, as described [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259). A brief overview:

If you control the Dockerfile, you run `HOST_UID=$(id -u)` and `HOST_GID=$(id -g)` and generate a Dockerfile that expands `$HOST_GID` and `$HOST_UID` in the below two commands:

```
RUN groupadd -g $HOST_GID mygroup
RUN useradd -l -u $HOST_UID -g mygroup myuser
```

Use the generated Dockerfile with the ID's filled in, to build your image.

If you don't control the Dockerfile, [here’s a container pattern for assigning the userid / groupid at runtime in a way that’s easily portable.](https://github.com/Graham42/mapped-uid-docker)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to copy your source files into the container and then chown them.

```
ADD ./ /var/www
RUN chown....
```

It is better to copy files into the container when in production.

Good reading here: https://medium.com/@basi/docker-compose-from-development-to-production-88000124a57c